# Retrieve records from sqllite using Array list

Tags: android, sqlite

I am retrieving all records from database and saving all records in array list.when i show array list records ,repeated data displayed,i don't know what's the prolblem??

Calling this function in view_record class:

```
public ArrayList<tuple> getdata() {         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        tuple obj=new tuple();
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, PROJECTION_ALL, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(c == null) {
         return null;
        }

        ArrayList <tuple> data = new ArrayList<tuple>();

        // String result = " ";

        int i=0;

        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
                  obj.ROWID= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID));
                  obj.CNAME= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_CNAME));
                  obj.SNAME= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_SNAME));
                  obj.FAMILY= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_FAMILY));
                  obj.LOCATION= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_LOCATION));
                  obj.IMAGE1= c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE1));
                  obj.IMAGE2= c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE2));
                  obj.IMAGE3= c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_IMAGE3));
                  data.add(i, obj);
                  i++;
       }
       c.close();

       return data;     }
```

My view_record class

```
public class view_record extends Activity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.db_view);

        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSqlinfo);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);      

        db_handler info=new db_handler(this);
        info.open();    

        //   Log.d("abc", "adb");

        ArrayList <tuple> data=info.getdata();
        Log.d("abc", "adb");

        String result="";

        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
               result +=" " + data.get(i).ROWID + "   " + data.get(i).CNAME + "   " + data.get(i).SNAME + "   " + data.get(i).FAMILY + "    " + data.get(i).LOCATION + "\n";

              tv.setText(result);
              img.setImageBitmap(Utilities.getImage(data.get(0).IMAGE2));
        }
        info.close();   } }
```

I want to view as follows :

```
   " 1 cname sname family location "
   " 2 cname sname family location "
```

But i am getting
             "  2 cname sname family location "
             "  2 cname sname family location "

Means last record displayed two times.

and one more thing ,i want to get all records where cname=something,getting error while doing it so

Comment: on start of `for loop` add this line `obj=new tuple();`

Comment: I edited your code.  In future, please use the "code sample" button and don't try to space your code out using tabs.  I've also added whitespace to aid readability (which you should get into the habit of doing) and finally, removed "Android" from the subject.  There is no need to tag subjects since you supply a tag for the question anyway.

Comment: thanx it works 4 me...but i want to get my second questions answer
i want to get all records where cname=something,getting error while doing it????????????

Comment: to notify any person use @taimoorminhas notation. as I did in this comment. other wise no one be notify. So your question can not be answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

you are not making a new project in your for loop. That is whay you are getting same results. just do...

on start of `for loop` add this line `obj=new tuple();`

**Answer to your Second Question**

```
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
               result +=" " + data.get(i).ROWID + "   " + data.get(i).CNAME + "   " + data.get(i).SNAME + "   " + data.get(i).FAMILY + "    " + data.get(i).LOCATION + "\n";


              img.setImageBitmap(Utilities.getImage(data.get(0).IMAGE2));
        }
   tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
```